# htaccess reorder subpath order

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website with a category and a brand listing. These act as a filter, when I use one filter everything is all right. When I combine both the URLs are `www.domain.com/productlisting/category/cat1/brand/brand1.html` and `www.domain.com/productlisting/brand/brand1/category/cat1.html`. This is duplicate content - to eliminate this I want to have just one possibility left `(www.domain.com/productlisting/brand/brand1/category/cat1.html)`. The webpage generates both variants so I wanted to put a rewrite rule in the `.htaccess` file, but it didn't work.
Maybe someone could give me a hint for this:

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule /productlisting/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/brand/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)\.html  /productlisting/brand/$2/category/$1.html  [L]
```

Comment: "It didn't work" isn't very specific, perhaps explain what happened / didn't happen.

Comment: sorry for the delay, there is no redirection.

Comment: I used http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ for testing – this tool said rewrite rule is ok.

Answer (score 0):

It works with

> RedirectMatch 301 /produktuebersicht/category/([^/]+)/brand/([^/]+).html /produktuebersicht/brand/$2/category/$1.html

;-)